# Cпособы закрытия окна

Tags: javascript, html, css, всплывающее-окно, окно

Я видел в интернете, что окно скрывается с помощью метода `hide` или `display` в случае его закрытия (а не удаление по закрытию на крестик). А каким образом можно реализовать настоящее закрытие окна, а не его сокрытие? Может есть оператор close для закрытия окна? Как я полагаю

```js
closeButton.onclick = function(){
    win.close();
}
```

Подскажите есть ли у окна в `javascript` метод `close` (встроенный в него), который не скрывает его, а удаляет его.

К примеру, [Пример](https://dbmast.ru/adaptivnye-modalnye-formy-vhoda-i-registracii)

И вообще, помимо - закрытия окна по крестику, если можно, приведите все варианты закрытия окна.

Comment: Имеется ввиду полное удаление из DOM-дерева? [Типа так](https://gomakethings.com/removing-an-element-from-the-dom-with-vanilla-js/)?

Comment: Не понятно что вы видели и что хотите? По сути авторизация это отдельная форма с элементами которая может быть на отдельной странице или окне или в каком-нибудь контейнере. Так вот что вы хотите и в каком случае?

Comment: Проясните чтобы было понятно всем. Приведите пример кода или ссылку на библиотеку, где окно не может удалиться, а только скрывается, и чем это доставляет проблем.

Comment: @PavelGrishaev прояснил вопрос?

Comment: @juniordeveloper , судя по указанному вами примеру попапа, вы просто можете взять какой-то другой попап, у которого работа реализована иначе, и у которого есть метод закрытия. Таких полно в сети. А такие что просто показывают/скрывают действительно зачастую не удобны.

Answer (score 2):

1. Операторов `hide` и `display` не существует. Может быть атрибут (и свойство - к счастью, тут они синхронизированы) `hidden` у dom-элемента, либо метод `hide` у jQuery. А `display` - вообще свойство стиля.
2. Если для модального она используется элемент `dialog` (браузерная поддержка которого пока так себе), то у него есть методы `show` и `close`, впрочем, при этом он по-прежнему остаётся в dom-дереве.
3. Ответ на вопрос - метод `remove`, только не забудь позаботиться о том, чтобы таким образом не текла память из-за забытых ссылок и кривых обработчиков.
4. Для более старых браузеров его надо заменить методом `removeChild` на родительском элементе.
5. А уничтожить на js ничего нельзя. Скрипту не предоставляется управление сборкой мусора.

Comment: а как вы нашли метод remove (на `learn.javascript.ru` - нет для окон)? Как загуглить не зная имени метода?

Comment: @juniordeveloper 6. Окон тоже нет.